# SSL Connection works on Android 6, fails on Android 5 and lower - No peer certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, dns

I just recognized that my app does not get a SSL Connection to my server for devices running android 5 or lower.
Here comes the error:

javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

I tested my app during development on Android 6 and all worked properly.

My domain contains the SSL-Certificate, so I did not need to put it on the server.
Do you know how to get a SSL-Connection for devices which are not running Android 6?

Thanks very much

Comment: Do you mean to ask about *Android 5*, or *6*?

Comment: It still works on Android 6, so my question is about Android 5 and lower versions.

Comment: You may have a mistake in the last sentence: *Do you know how to get a SSL-Connection for devices which are not running **Android 6**?*

Comment: No, it ist the first time I did it. I thought it would work on all versions if it works on Android 6.